# Flutter Bottom to Fixed Material Button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm a beginner in the flutter , I find some  solution for  position fixed material button in the page bottom, I trie  bottom navigation but  not working there, any solution for this?

Thanks

```
import 'dart:ui';
    
    import 'package:crmapp/widgets/components/alert.dart';
    import 'package:crmapp/widgets/theme/constants.dart';
    import 'package:crmapp/widgets/theme/constants.dart';
    import 'package:crmapp/widgets/theme/constants.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    
    class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
    }
    
    class _SignUpScreenState extends State< SignUpScreen > {
      //validation controller
      TextEditingController fNameController = new TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController lNameController = new TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController nickNameController = new TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController phoneController = new TextEditingController();
    
      bool _isButtonEnabled = false;
      //final _controller = TextEditingController();
      bool isConfirm=false;
      check (BuildContext context){
        if(fNameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
            lNameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
            nickNameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
            phoneController.text.isNotEmpty){
          setState(() {
            _isButtonEnabled = true;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _isButtonEnabled = false;
          });
        }
      }
      final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        /*   double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;*/
    
        return Scaffold(
    
    
          body: SafeArea(
    
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
    
    
                _signUp(),
    
              ],
    
    
            ),
    
          ),
    
        );
    
      }
    
    
      Widget _signUp() {
        return Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Color(0xFF2A3476),
                Color(0xFF2A3476),
              ],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
            ),
          ),
           child: Form(
        key: formKey,
    
        child: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 36.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Create Account",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 34.0,fontFamily: "medium",
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        ),
                      ),
                      /*  SizedBox(
                       height: 10.0,
                     ),*/
                      /*      Text(
                       "Enter to a beautiful world",
                       style:  TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         fontSize: 20.0,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    
                       ),
                     )*/
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Hello, sign up to",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 29,
                            fontFamily: "regular",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "continue",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 29,
                            fontFamily: "regular",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'First Name',
                          style:
                          TextStyle(  fontSize: 15,
                            fontFamily: "regular",),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 12.0,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                          controller: fNameController,
                          onChanged: (val){
                            check(context);
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                              hintText: "",
                            /*  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )*/),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Last Name',
                          style:
                          TextStyle(
    
                              fontSize: 15,
                            fontFamily: "regular",
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 12.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: lNameController,
                          onChanged: (val){
                            check(context);
                          },
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
    
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                              hintText: "",
                           /*   prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )*/),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Nick Name',
                          style:
                          TextStyle(  fontSize: 15,
                            fontFamily: "regular",),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 12.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
    
                          controller: nickNameController,
                          onChanged: (val){
                            check(context);
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                              hintText: "",
                              /*prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                                color: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                              )*/),
                        ),
    
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Mobile Number',
                          style:
                          TextStyle(  fontSize: 15,
                            fontFamily: "regular",),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 12.0,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: phoneController,
                          onChanged: (val){
                            check(context);
                          },
                          maxLength: 10,
                         /* validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Please enter some text';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },*/
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                            filled: true,
    
                            fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                            hintText: "077xxxxxxx",
    
                          ),
                        ),
    
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
    
    
    
    
                        Container(    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: MaterialButton(
                                  height: 44,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                                  },
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
                                  color:   _isButtonEnabled ? Color(0xFF2A3476) : Color(0x201E1E99),
                                  elevation: 0,
                                  highlightElevation: 0,
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Next",
                                        style: TextStyle(color: m_fillColor,fontSize: 18,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600  ,
                                          fontFamily: "regular",),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
    
                        ),
                      /*  Container(
                          child: Container(
    
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                      offset: Offset(2, 4),
                                      blurRadius: 5,
                                      spreadRadius: 2)
                                ],
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    colors: [
                                      Color(0xFF2A3476),
                                      Color(0xFF2A3476)
                                    ])),
                            child: Text(
                              'Next',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
    
                            ),
    
                          ),
    
                        ),*/
    
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            RichText(
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                                TextSpan(
                                    text: "Already have an account?",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: m_titleColor,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontFamily: "regular")),
                                TextSpan(
                                    text: " Sign in",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color:  Color(0xFF2A3476),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        fontFamily: "medium")),
                              ]),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),  SizedBox(
                          height:100.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    
        ),
        );
      }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: I don't get what you want, do you need "Next" button to be at bottom of the page or the whole signup container?

Comment: @SajadAbdollahi Actually I want to put MaterialButton in   page bottom , its should be a position fixed and need to scroller forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to put a position fixed material button at the bottom.You can use floating action button with its location inside the Scaffold widget.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: new Icon(Icons.check),
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
      onPressed: () {}),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
```

As you can see I have put them inside your Scaffold widget like this.

```
    class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  //validation controller
  TextEditingController fNameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lNameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nickNameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneController = new TextEditingController();

  bool _isButtonEnabled = false;
  //final _controller = TextEditingController();
  bool isConfirm = false;
  check(BuildContext context) {
    if (fNameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        lNameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        nickNameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        phoneController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _isButtonEnabled = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isButtonEnabled = false;
      });
    }
  }

  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*   double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;*/

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            _signUp(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          elevation: 0.0,
          child: new Icon(Icons.check),
          backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
          onPressed: () {}),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }

  Widget _signUp() {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Color(0xFF2A3476),
            Color(0xFF2A3476),
          ],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
        ),
      ),
      child: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 36.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Create Account",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 34.0,
                          fontFamily: "medium",
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        ),
                      ),
                      /*  SizedBox(
                       height: 10.0,
                     ),*/
                      /*      Text(
                       "Enter to a beautiful world",
                       style:  TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         fontSize: 20.0,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    
                       ),
                     )*/
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Hello, sign up to",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 29,
                            fontFamily: "regular",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "continue",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 29,
                            fontFamily: "regular",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'First Name',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontFamily: "regular",
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 12.0,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                          controller: fNameController,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            check(context);
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                            hintText: "",
                            /*  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )*/
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Last Name',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontFamily: "regular",
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 12.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: lNameController,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            check(context);
                          },
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                            hintText: "",
                            /*   prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )*/
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Nick Name',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontFamily: "regular",
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 12.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/

                          controller: nickNameController,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            check(context);
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                            hintText: "",
                            /*prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.people_outline_rounded,
                                color: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                              )*/
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Mobile Number',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontFamily: "regular",
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 12.0,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: phoneController,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            check(context);
                          },
                          maxLength: 10,
                          /* validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Please enter some text';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },*/
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                          /* keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,*/
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                            hintText: "077xxxxxxx",
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: MaterialButton(
                                  height: 44,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    FocusScope.of(context)
                                        .requestFocus(FocusNode());
                                  },
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(8.0))),
                                  color: _isButtonEnabled
                                      ? Color(0xFF2A3476)
                                      : Color(0x201E1E99),
                                  elevation: 0,
                                  highlightElevation: 0,
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Next",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        fontFamily: "regular",
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        /*  Container(
                          child: Container(
    
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                      offset: Offset(2, 4),
                                      blurRadius: 5,
                                      spreadRadius: 2)
                                ],
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    colors: [
                                      Color(0xFF2A3476),
                                      Color(0xFF2A3476)
                                    ])),
                            child: Text(
                              'Next',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
    
                            ),
    
                          ),
    
                        ),*/

                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            RichText(
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                                TextSpan(
                                    text: "Already have an account?",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                        fontFamily: "regular")),
                                TextSpan(
                                    text: " Sign in",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xFF2A3476),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        fontFamily: "medium")),
                              ]),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 100.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I added, but your solution to cant added my validation, can you put it using my code

Comment: you can add the next button as floating action button and add validation using formkey of your form.

Comment: @Hi, its working can you have any idea , how to add  RichText() undear floating area?

Comment: floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          elevation: 0.0,
          child: Column(
            children:[
              Icon(Icons.check,color:Colors.black),
              SizedBox(height:10),
              Text("test",style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
              //SizedBox(height:30),
            ]
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {}),
You can try this to add more children inside that floating area.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve the same.

1. Using Stack Widget. Consider a code snippet like a below:

   ```
   return Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
              children: children
                ..add(Container(
                  height: 56, // button height, so could scroll underlapping area
                )))),
    ),
    Positioned(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: button,
      ),
    )
   ],
   );
   ```
2. Using Expanded Widget. Consider a code snippet like a below:

   ```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    title: 'My Layout',
    theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: MyHomePage(),
    );
    }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("Align Bottom Demo"),
    ),
    body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
    Text("Text 1"),
    Text("Text 2"),
    Expanded(
        child: new Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Icon(Icons.star),
                new Text("Bottom Text")
              ],
            )))
     ]),
     );
     }
     }
   ```

Comment: not working in my code, can you added it  to using  my code